# Cookie values returned as undefined

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm trying to set and read it back but it is return 'Undefined'.

The .js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
function () {

    addParameters();

    function addParameters() {
        jQuery('#Parameters').append('<form id="form" action="" method="" autocomplete="false"><fieldset><label>Please select the month and year you wish to search</label><section><label>Month</label><select name="Month" id="monthsDropdown"><option value="Months" disabled="disabled">Select a Month</option><option value="01">January</option><option value="02">February</option><option value="03">March</option><option value="04">April</option><option value="05">May</option><option value="06">June</option><option value="07">July</option><option value="08">August</option><option value="09">September</option><option value="10">October</option><option value="11">November</option><option value="12">December</option><option value="00">Test</option></select><select name="Year" id="yearsDropdown"><option value="Years" disabled="disabled">Select a Year</option><option value=""></option><option value="2010">2010</option></section></fieldset></form>');

        jQuery('#form').append('<input type="submit" id="buttonSubmit" class="btn blue" value="Submit" />');}


    jQuery('#form').submit(function () {
        console.log(jQuery(this).serializeArray());

        var data = (jQuery(this).serializeArray());
        createCookie("formData", JSON.stringify(data), 1);
        var data1 = JSON.parse(readCookie("formData"));
        alert(data1.Month);

        return false;
    });

**The html:**
<div class="widget" id="Parameters">
</div>
```

The cookie appears to be setting correcting. The cookie data looks like this:
    [{"name":"Month","value":"07"},{"name":"Year","value":"2010"}]
but the alert returns 'Undefined. If I leave out the .Month from the alert, it returns object Object.

I'm at a loss as to what is wrong so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: apparently the data1 variable does not have an 'class-attribute' Month. Find out what IS in data1 with console.log(data1). This'll help you out!

Comment: I suggest using `console.log` instead of `alert`.  It'll give you more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
[{"name":"Month","value":"07"},{"name":"Year","value":"2010"}]
```

If this is your data, then `data1.Month` does not exist.  This is an array of objects.

```
{"name":"Month","value":"07"}
```

and

```
{"name":"Year","value":"2010"}
```

These objects, have a `name` property and a `value` property.  To get the month, you'd need to loop through the array, and find the object with the value of `name` equal to `'Month'`.